# Priming fuel system from fuel tank?

Tags: fuel-system, car, diesel, fuel-pump

Mechanic changed my Focus 2014`s diesel fuel filter, then because he didn't know the correct method to bleed the system, instead he pressurized the fuel tank with compressor. Car ran fine. But the question is **can you damage anything with this practice, like fuel pump?**

I didn't find any info about this kind of practice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given the pressure the fuel pump is designed to provide, then no, I doubt any damage will happen. Some mechanics use a method to "suck" the fuel through, others pre-fill the new filter first... What do you consider to be the "correct" method?

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for clarifying Mike. I'm certainly not an expert on this topic, but what I mean by "the correct method" is to use the second/electronic fuel pump by cycling ignition for 5 times, each waiting 6 seconds. But if it works by that way and won't cause any problem than it's fine. But finding nearly nothing about this practice in Google worried me at first.

Comment: As long as they don't put too much pressure on the tank it is a time proven method to prime the fuel system on gas and diesel vehicles when they wont self prime for some reason.